# Getting current page name on MVC Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On my MVC project I have a form on the Footer within the Layout page, I have to know on which page this form was submitted.

For example: for this URL:

http://www.test.com/myWebSite.test/home

I need the `home` part.

I tried that:

```
Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
```

But I'm getting the name of the Action, for ex:

> SubmitForm

I am not sure how to do it, any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to get the route to the action you've POSTed to?

Comment: What is the "current page name"? It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: @DavidG  Please see my updated question.

Comment: What is "home" here? Is it part of your route?

Comment: @ChrisPratt I edited my question, it's not a duplicate anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the current action name or controller name try this:

```
string actionName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
string controllerName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you! Working!

Comment: I'm sorry but I realized that I'm not looking for the Controller name but the current page name, sorry!

Comment: Then you would likely need the Action name (the first line of code)